# Multiple filter with TableView in javafx

Tags: java, javafx-2, tableview

I have created table in javafx2.2 with filter for filtering data. For example I have two columns like (First Name , Last Name). The First Name column has same name in many rows with different Last Name. So i would like to add two filter for filtering First Name then i like to filter Last Name Based on First Name Filter.

Comment: Are you talking about filtering or sorting in this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `TableView#getSortOrder` method :

```
public final ObservableList<TableColumn<S,?>> getSortOrder()

Returns:
An ObservableList containing zero or more TableColumn instances.
```

The sortOrder list defines the order in which TableColumn instances are sorted:

- An empty sortOrder list means that no sorting is being applied to the TableView.
- If the sortOrder list contains only one TableColumn, TableView will be sorted using the sortType and comparator properties of this TableColumn (assuming `TableColumn.sortable` is true).
- If the sortOrder list contains multiple TableColumn instances, then TableView is initially sorted based on the properties of the first TableColumn. If two elements are considered equal, then the second TableColumn in the list is used to determine ordering. This repeats until the results from all TableColumn comparators are considered, if necessary.

You just have to put first and last columns there having previously `setSortable(true)` called for both columns.