# Fast filtering in javafx tableview

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2, tableview

I need to implement a filter in javafx tableview with huge data (around 100,000 ),

I have tried [this tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-2-tableview-filter). It works but filtering is really slow as compared to swing [sorting and filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting), [code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableFilterDemoProject/src/components/TableFilterDemo.java).

Can anyone help me to increase speed.

What is happening right now is as I type textproperty change fire up and filterdata but it is slow, I need something which shows filter result with typing quickly as happening in swing.

thanks in advance.

p.s I have also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539274/multiple-filter-with-tableview-in-javafx).

Comment: How is this any different from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16805845/1076463) ?

Comment: sorting part is done   

I now need to add filter which filters out data according to text change in text box,

I have given link for swing application or oracle website which works pretty fast (add 100,000) data point but my javafx application doesnot work fast (see link given in question for filtering in javafx)

Comment: For [suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805845/javafx-tableview-sort-is-really-slow-how-to-improve-sort-speed-as-in-java-swing) It is working with same speed as that of sorting but I want to know how swing implement it that it retrieve data too fast for filtering as compared to javafx

Comment: @ b.pradeep - Did you get any solution for this question?

Comment: @IJP unfortunately no
you have to write custom filtering by traversing through your table but JavaFx 8 looks promising, but I haven't explored it yet.

Answer (score 10):

## `FilteredList`

You may use [`FilteredList`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.base/javafx/collections/transformation/FilteredList.html) in JavaFX 8+.

```
ObservableList<YourObjectClass> actualList = ...;
FilteredList<YourObjectClass> filteredList = new FilteredList<>(actualList);

TableView table = ...;
table.setItems(filteredList);

// to filter
filteredList.setPredicate(
    new Predicate<YourObjectClass>(){
        public boolean test(YourObjectClass t){
            return false; // or true
        }
    }
);
```

as fast as swing, (maybe faster then swing... ). (I tested with 100000 rows)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following code. It works fine for me..

```
ObservableList data =  table.getItems();
textfield.textProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) -> {
            if (oldValue != null && (newValue.length() < oldValue.length())) {
                table.setItems(data);
            }
            String value = newValue.toLowerCase();
            ObservableList<T> subentries = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

            long count = table.getColumns().stream().count();
            for (int i = 0; i < table.getItems().size(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
                    String entry = "" + table.getColumns().get(j).getCellData(i);
                    if (entry.toLowerCase().contains(value)) {
                        subentries.add(table.getItems().get(i));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            table.setItems(subentries);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this snippet of code for filtering but really i didn't test in huge data case

```
textField.textProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {

        @Override
        public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
            if(textField.textProperty().get().isEmpty()) {
                tableView.setItems(dataList);
                return;
            }
            ObservableList<ClassModel> tableItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            ObservableList<TableColumn<ClassModel, ?>> cols = tableView.getColumns();
            for(int i=0; i<dataList.size(); i++) {

                for(int j=0; j<cols.size(); j++) {
                    TableColumn col = cols.get(j);
                    String cellValue = col.getCellData(dataList.get(i)).toString();
                    cellValue = cellValue.toLowerCase();
                    if(cellValue.contains(textField.textProperty().get().toLowerCase())) {
                        tableItems.add(data.get(i));
                        break;
                    }                        
                }
            }
            tableView.setItems(tableItems);

        }
    });
```

where ClassModel is your Model Class

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1)
{
    searchField. textProperty().addListener((obs, oldText, newText) -> { 
    search();
}); 
 

@FXML private void search()
{    
  String keyword = searchField.getText();
  if (keyword.equals("")) {
     table.setItems(data);
 } else {
     ObservableList<Product> filteredData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
     for (Product product : data) {
         if(product.getName().contains(keyword))
             filteredData.add(product);
     }
   
     table.setItems(filteredData);
   }
}
```

Comment: You may use that